# Changing URL schemes in wordpress without breaking old URLs

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, blogs, friendly-url

I started a blog and after a couple posts decided I didn't like the /2009/03/26/foo-bar scheme for URLs (I changed to just /foo-bar).  But for the couple posts posted before I changed this, I want to add rewrite rules so the old URLs don't break.

I've tried every variation of the following I could think of in the .htaccess file, to no avail:  (note that everything here except the "first-post" and "second-post" lines is wordpress boilerplate)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /2009/03/25/first-post /first-post
RewriteRule /2009/03/26/second-post /second-post

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Permalink migration plugin](http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/permalinks-migration-plugin/) from Dean Lee.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^\d*/\d*/\d*/(.*) /$1
```

Comment: Doesn't work!  I like the generality of the solution if it did work though. :)

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution that I just tried that works is to actually create the directories and subdirectories 2009/03/25/ etc and then add an index.php file containing the following:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://example.com/first-post');
?>
```

Comment: Turns out this solution is really not viable since it screws up the tracking of statistics on readers that feedburner does.